# How to show ICICI Payment gateway in magento checkout one page

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate ICICI Payseal gateway with Magento. I have successfully tested the payment gateway with test file. But I am not getting the how to make it live as I am not able to see it on checkout page , also not in admin section. Can someone help me out.

Comment: Have you add icici payment gateway as payment methods in you magento installation?

Comment: No I have not added icici payment gateway as payment method. I installed default magento and now we have a ICICI payment gateway to integrate. If I need to add a icici payment gateway as payment methods, then how should i proceed.

Comment: Follow this two links of how you can add new payment method in magento http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module and other one http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/

Comment: So I have to develop a separate payment method.

Comment: Yes, Without payment module how you can think to display icici payment methods on checkout page>?

Comment: So after developing payment method, I have to place ICICI parameters right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A payment module will be displayed on checkout if it meets certain criterias:
1. It should be active.
2. It should be available for website or store where you are testing.
3. It should be available for zone the customer is from.

Plus there are few more criteria that will depend on what all configuration related controls exist.

Comment: Have you integrated ICICI payment gateway in magento because they have provided me an api but its just for testing, its not a full module.

Comment: No I havent. My reply is applicable to any payment module in general.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to develop a complete module with the provided files by ICICI bank, they provide a code in core php which will work perfectly fine.